# XSLT - Move only specified content into node

Tags: xml, xslt

My Input XML is like as,

```
<section counter="yes" level="2">
<title>Course of Illness Following Stroke(<link idref="c003_f001">Fig. 3.1</link>)</title>
<section counter="yes" level="3">
```

Output should be,

```
<section counter="yes" level="2">
<title>Course of Illness Following Stroke</title>
<para><link idref="c003_f001">(Fig. 3.1)</link></para>
<section counter="yes" level="3">
```

Whenever the link is appearing within 'title' with parenthesis'()' then it should be moved to next para. If 'para' is not appeared then we should create and move the entire 'link' with parenthesis'()'.

I have wrote the XSLT but it's not given the desired output.

```
 <xsl:template match="title/text()">
    <xsl:if test="matches(., '\(') and following::node()[self::link]">
        <para>
        <xsl:copy>                        
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        </para>
    </xsl:if>  
    <xsl:if test="matches(., '\)') and following::node()[self::link]">
        <xsl:copy>                        
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>  
</xsl:template>
```

Could you please guide us to resolve this issue.

Comment: XSLT version? 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: We are using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Can you confirm the following sequence of nodes in `<para>` -> `<link idref="c003_f001">(Fig. 3.1</link>)` ? Are you sure the parentheses are not enclosing the text as `(Fig 3.1)`

Comment: HI Ankit, i have updated output in description. The paranthesis should be enclosed with link like as '<link idref="c003_f001">(Fig. 3.1)</link>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make much sense to use `xsl:apply-templates` within a template that matches a text node. (And another issue: You do not really require `matches()`, as you do not need a regular expression to search for single round brackets; instead, `contains()` would be sufficient.)

A procedure for your scenario could works like this: Look for `title` that contains `link` surrounded by brackets (combining `*-sibling::` and `substring-*()`). You can do that completely with XPath. In matching elements you just recompose the title, starting with copying `title` and filling it with all text before `(`. It could be neccessary to adjust this, depending on the possible content of title: Maybe it can contain other elements preceding to `link` (let us know if that is the case). After that, just insert a copy of `link` into a `para`. And that's it.

```
<xsl:template
    match="title[link[ends-with(preceding-sibling::text(), '(') and starts-with(following-sibling::text(), ')')]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(text()[1], '(')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <para>
        <!-- edit -->
        <!--<xsl:copy-of select="link"/>-->
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="parenthesize" select="link"/>
        <!-- end edit -->
    </para>
</xsl:template>

<!-- edit: new template -->
<xsl:template match="link" mode="parenthesize">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

PS. I assume that you use identity transform for all other elements.

Comment: @ Friedemann: Thank you for your response. The main motive is move the 'parenthesis' into link as shown in description. While running above XSLT, we are getting below output. <section level="2">
<title>Course of Illness Following Stroke</title><para>(<link idref="c003_f001" target="figure">Fig. 3.1</link>)</para>
<section level="3">. In that, Parenthesis are not moved into link text.

Comment: Please tell me what your problem is, instead of bulking code into a comment.

Comment: I see. I think I can fix that. Actually, if you apply the XSL from my solution, you should not see the parentheses at all.

Comment: Hi Friedemann, It's working properly as per my expected output. Thanku..